# SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I try to populate **SQLAlchemy** model from dictionary. The code part is like that.

```
data = dict(request.form)
c=customer(**data)
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

All is fine when form does not have date field. However when add date time field to form, it is not possible to fill model. I get this error message.

> SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, register_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: [{'first_name': ['jhon'], 'register_date': ['2010-01-01'], 'last_name': ['snow']}]]

```
class customer(db.Model):
first_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
last_name= db.Column(db.String(200))
register_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Prolly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344237/error-sqlite-datetime-type-only-accepts-python-datetime-and-date-objects-a, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607244/sqlite-date-type-only-accepts-python-date-objects-as-input, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536368/python-datatime-object-issue-with-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644808/insertmany-into-the-in-memory-sqllite-db-sqlite-date-type-only-accepts-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975170/statementerror-sqlite-date-type-only-accepts-python-date-objects-as-input. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a "datetime" type, so this is something specific to the python library you're using. What does its documentation say about storing dates and times?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `register_date` is a string in your code. You need to convert the string to a `datetime` or `date` object before calling `c=customer(**data)`.

Comment: register_date is form field and it is a input as other fields. There is not problem when set register_date as c.register_date=form.register_date.data.

Comment: What's the type of `data['register_date']` in your original post and what's the type of `form.register_date.data`?